# My pager code doesn't work

Tags: 7, paging

I'm using the following code just to see if the paging works in Drupal 7, but I'm having trouble to set it to work.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(5);

$headers = array(t('node'), t('Title'));
$rows = array();
$result = $query->execute();

foreach ($result as $record) {
  $rows[] .= array($record->nid, $record->title);
}

$output = theme('table', $headers, $rows);
return $output . theme('pager');
```

I'm not so good with PHP, so can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the string concatenation operator with an array; you need the assignment operator.

```
$rows[] = array($record->nid, $record->title);
```

```
$headers = array(t('node'), t('Title'));
$rows = array();

$nodes = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(5)
  ->execute();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $rows[] = array($node->nid, $node->title);
}

return theme('table', $headers, $rows) . theme('pager');
```

Depending from which function contains that code, it could also be re-written as follows:

```
$page = array();
$rows = array();

$nodes = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(5)
  ->execute();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $rows[] = array($node->nid, $node->title);
}

$page['table'] = array(
  '#rows' => $rows, 
  '#header' => array(t('Node'), t('Title')), 
  '#theme' => 'table', 
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'), 
);

$page['pager'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'pager', 
);

return $page;
```